# Excel opens a file to the wrong sheet within the workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

When I work on a worksheet, and when I stop I leave the 3rd page open, I had saved my document and had closed my workbook and while closing i had kept it on 3rd sheet itself.

When opening, I need the workbook to start with sheet number 1.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Excel is built to open where the last save occurred, in the exact state of the save.

In order to change this, you must re-save it where you'd lke it to open, or use a macro in the workbook that sets the view you want open opening. This requires entering some VBA and making sure macros are enabled.

Press <kbd>alt F11</kbd> within the workbook to enter VBA
Enter this within the `ThisWorkBook` object on the left and change "sheet1" to the name of the sheet you want opened.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```

You will have to save the document as `Excel Macro Enabled Workbook` or `.xlsm`

Now, whenever the workbook is opened, it will prompt to enable macros. If you enable them, the sheet you selected will be the activesheet.

If it doesn't prompt you, go to [the trust center](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/view-my-options-and-settings-in-the-trust-center-HA010033776.aspx#BM13) and go to macro settings and set the desired setting.

Comment: how do i enable macro? please tell me!!

Comment: It's outlined in the answer

Comment: It does not work!!

Comment: save as macro enabled workbook. Look in the trust center.

Comment: huh that also not works